# How to test a function with N distinct paths?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have a function which validates a model class where it has to check every member of the class to be non-null or non-empty in case of a String.

The logic for this `is_complete` function is something like this:

```
def is_complete(profile):
    if profile.first_name in (None, ''):
        return False
    elif profile.last_name in (None, ''):
        return False
    elif profile.dob is None:
        return False
    .
    .
    .# and checks so on for all members of the profile instance
    .
    .

    return True
```

My question since the number of possible paths the execution can take is quite large and increases in proportion to the number of member variables of `profile` to be checked, how does one reliably write tests for all the possible paths?

Right now, I have two simple test cases:

1. where only *some* of the members are set and checks `assertFalse(is_complete(foo))`
2. where *all* the members are set and checks `assertTrue(is_complete(foo))`

But I have a feeling that this may not be enough.

Comment: In unit testing, you don't necessarily want to test every path. With many functions that isn't even possible or practical. You simply want to test enough. If a function is complex that is probably a sign that it should be broken down into smaller functions.

Comment: You should seriously rethink your class design. Ideally it shouldn't be possible to create partially initialized objects in the first place. Constructors should take care of this. If some of the data you need for initializing your class is not available at construction time, try to extract it into a different class.

Comment: @FrankPuffer an instance with it's members as empty strings or nulls is not considered _partially initialized_ because it represents a valid state the instance can be in. It might represent a form of which some fields the user has willingly left blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by having `MxN` paths. In the posted code you have as many paths as fields + 1.

Create a helper method that creates a `profile` that is complete and passes `is_complete`.

Add a test method to verify `is_complete(profile)` is `True` for the complete `profile`.

Add one test method for each field, with the following steps:

- Call the helper method to create a complete profile that we know would pass `is_complete`
- Break the field under test
- Verify that `is_complete` returns `False`

You will have as many test methods as fields + 1.

Btw, instead of this:

> ```
> if profile.first_name in (None, ''):
> ```

You can writer simpler:

```
if not profile.first_name:
```

Comment: You're right. That's only `n` paths. Sorry about that, I will correct the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this with randomization:

- Write a function that creates a random Profile object with all the fields filled (could be random, but valid).
- Randomly change one or more fields to either None or empty
- Pass the object to the is_complete() function.

I can show this only in Java with [Qala Datagen](https://github.com/qala-io/datagen). I assume you're interested in the negative paths, so it can look like this:

```
@Test void profileIsNotComplete_ifAtLeastOneFieldIsBlank() {
    Profile p = Profile.random();
    callOneOrMore(
        () -> profile.setName(nullOrEmpty()),
        () -> profile.setLastName(nullOrEmpty()),
        ...);
    assertFalse(profile.isComplete();
}
```

Note, that this code actually tests more - it also checks the combination of fields set to null/empty. If in Python there are no such libs, you can write some utility methods for yourself.

**NB**: only one path is going to be tested per one execution. You can run it many times (a thousand?) to make sure that all the paths pass. Then in CI you can run it only once if this is not a mission-critical functionality and you're not afraid that it's going to break often.

Otherwise if you really want this to be **covered 100% for every invocation**, you can violate some of the good practices and just combine all these tests in one (otherwise there are going to be too many tests which complicate reading them):

```
@Test void profileIsNotComplete_ifOneFieldIsBlank() {
    assertFalse(Profile.random().setName(null).isComplete());
    assertFalse(Profile.random().setName("").isComplete());

    assertFalse(Profile.random().setLastName(null).isComplete());
    assertFalse(Profile.random().setLastName("").isComplete());
    ...
}
```

This doesn't test combinations though, but you can combine both approaches. The positive case is very easy in both approaches:

```
@Test void profileIsComplete_ifAllFieldsAreFilled() {
    assertTrue(Profile.random());
}
```

More info on randomized testing is [here](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html).